# this.removed(collection, id) makes somewhere exception thrown

Tags: collections, meteor, publish

I'm trying to inform the subscribers when a document is removed from a collection. I use this.removed(collection, id) when removed function of observeChanges is called:

```
Meteor.publish('tasks_listsPub', function(sUrl){
    ...
    var self = this;
    ocTasksLists.find().observeChanges({
        added: function (sId, oFields) {
            console.log('added:'+sId);
            self.added('tasks_lists', sId, oFields);
        },
        removed: function (sId) {
            console.log('removed:'+sId);
            self.removed('tasks_lists', sId); //throws a exception but sometimes it works in the browser
        },
        changed: function(sId, oFields){
            console.log('changed:'+sId);
            self.changed('tasks_lists', sId, oFields);
        }
    });
    var cVisibleTasksLists = ocTasksLists.find({_id: {$in: oWs.tasks_lists}});
    return cVisibleTasksLists;
});
```

The problem is that server throws exception:

```
removed:K8BBys7WRH4tTQRBg
Exception in queued task: Error: Removed nonexistent document K8BBys7WRH4tTQRBg
at _.extend.removed (app/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:181:17)
```

and the other browsers sometimes does not remove the deleted document. Any solution? Thx

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be publishing two conflicting datasets within one publish function.

The self.added, self.removed, and self.changed functions inside the observeChanges is trying to keep the client updated with **everything** in ocTasksLists.

`return cVisibleTasksLists;` however is trying to only publish the **subset** of ocTasksLists that match your query.

These conflicting publish instructions lead to the client sometimes not having all documents that are removed from ocTasksLists - your error message results.

Whether you want the whole dataset or the subset either can be done just by returning the database cursor as you do in your last two lines.  Removing the observeChanges function along with .added, .removed, and .changed functions will fix your error.